# GPO for "Non-Admin" Accounts

Tags: group-policy, mmc

Using this [guide](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/80061-apply-local-group-policy-non-administrators-windows-10-a.html) I have defined a policy:

```
Restrict access shutdown restart and sleep.
```

I then created a user via `control userpassword2` (Let's call it Joe).

The issue is, Joe can still access the  shutdown restart and sleep.

To test, I made another GPO specifying it to directly apply to Joe, but same thing happened, Joe can still access them.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, ensure the new user has not inherited the `Administrator` group within Windows. You can easily check this when logged in as the user:

`nank@tower> rsop` will generate a report on the policies applied (locate the path where you applied the script).

If you did not reboot the PC after making the policy and user, you will need to perform a `gpupdate.exe /force` and perform a reboot to login and get the new policies.

If still unsuccessful, first perform a `gpresult.exe /h report.html` to view a policy report, and then check [Event Viewer for Group Policy errors](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc749336(v=ws.10).aspx).

FWIW, steps provided worked perfectly on my test-case.